# ListView DragDrop Scrollbar not working

Tags: wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

DragDrop on a ListView kills drag on the VerticalScrollBar
The DragDrop event fires when I drag the ScrollBar and the ScrollBar does not move
I can still click above and below the ScrollBar and it moves and the DragDrop does not fire
I can drag the ScrollBar if I do so BEFORE clicking inside the ListView
If you need me to post more code please let me know

```
<ListView Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lbFields" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    SelectedIndex="-1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=MyGabeLib.FieldDefsAppliedGeneralUserNoTextMatch}"                  
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="0" Margin="1,1,1,1"
    AllowDrop="True"
    MouseMove="lbFields_MouseMove"                    
    DragDrop.Drop="ListView1_DragDrop">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by putting the `MouseMove` event handler on the data template for your items in the `ListView` instead on the `ListView` itself.

```html
<ListView Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lbFields" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="-1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=MyGabeLib.FieldDefsAppliedGeneralUserNoTextMatch}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
BorderThickness="0" Margin="1,1,1,1" AllowDrop="True" DragDrop.Drop="ListView1_DragDrop">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid MouseMove="lbFields_MouseMove">
        <!-- Add content here -->
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Since it was GridView was at the GridViewColumn.CellTemplate but it worked.  Thank you very much.